# how to increment global variable in a function pyt

Tags: function, counter, increment, python-3.9

I am making a program in python where this block of code doesn't run as expected

```
i = 0
def p():
    global i
    i+=1
    return i
print(f"{p()} "*2)
```

And it would be better if function has to be called in f-string.

Comment: What is it exactly that you expect, and what is it exactly that you get ?  While it is possible to see from the code what you'd actually get, it is not possible to see from the code what you expect.

Comment: I expected that this function is called 2 times in formated string so if "i" was 0 intialy after this function is called it should give answer 1 and on second time it should give the answer 2 but instead i get answer "1 1 " on the output.